# String index out of bound

Tags: java, string

```
 int b[]=new int[s.length()];
        for(int r=0;r<=s.length();r++)
        {
            b[r]=(int) s.charAt(r);
            b[r]=b[r]+2;
        }
```

I am getting a string index out of bounds error in line 4. Everything seems to be right. What's going wrong?

Comment: You don't need a cast because a `char` can be widened to an `int`; `b[r] = s.charAt(r) + 2;`

Comment: Change `r <= s.length()` to `r < s.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop logic a little

```
 int b[]=new int[s.length()];
        for(int r=0;r<s.length();r++)
        {
            b[r]=(int) s.charAt(r);
            b[r]=b[r]+2;
        }
```

Notice that loop should run upto r < s.length()

The problem is that at the end of the loop the value of r is greater than the maximum index of this array by 1 and thus the s.charAt() is causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
int b[]=new int[s.length()];
        for(int r=0;r<=s.length()-1 ;r++)
        {
            b[r]=(int) s.charAt(r);
            b[r]=b[r]+2;
        }
```

because `Array's index` starts from `0`,hence your iteration must run `length-1`

Comment: `for(int r=0;r<=s.length()-1 ;r++)`
must be

`for(int r=0;r<s.length()-1 ;r++)`

Comment: look at your for loop , it is the reason for `String out of bound exception`

Comment: I am not the downvoter and do not necessarily agree that you should be downvoted, but `for(int r=0;r<s.length() ;r++)` is easier to read.

Comment: @holidayCoder Look at the code yourself - it is correct.

Comment: sorry i didnt saw the `-1` part ,

Comment: @Holiday
It is correct.I have clearly mentioned the reason of Indexing.

Comment: im sorry , i didn't notice the `-1` in first place but thanks for telling me, ill be careful next time :)

Comment: Its okay @Holiday :)
undo your down vote please. :P

Comment: actually  I tried but unfortunately vote is locked and cant be changed untill post is edited

Answer (score 0):

dont forget array starts with 0 and 
array size or length starts with 1. 
the problem is somewhere in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You dont normally loop an array like this:

```
 for(int r=0;r<=s.length();r++)
```

just because the arrays are null index objects, i.e.

you can elements located in a range between 0 and length-1

**[0,length)**

i.e doing

```
 for(int r=0; r<s.length(); r++)
```

now, you are trying to get the element @length and that is the reason of the exception

Answer (score -1):

Yes you will get because strings `index`start from 0 and goes upto `(string length -1)` .
Suppose

`String str=new String("Graceful")`

then

`str.charAt(0)==G` and `str.charAt(7)==l` , so now **what you are doing is to access element at `charAt(8)==XXX` which contains nothing** and you are getting string index out of bound .
**MySolution** What you can do is change code

`for(int r=0;r<str.length();r++)`

or

`for(int r=0;r<=str.length()-1;r++)` .

Comment: Why my code was downvoted since it contains -1 too ? I dont understand @holidayCoder

Comment: Ok sorry i thought u did it , then who so ever did it kindly correct it .Because my code works perfectly fine .

Comment: you must edit it so it can be more readable

Comment: new here so i could only edit the bold , part ...dont know how to indent codes and add multiple spaces and new line :)

Comment: Its not me even,but let me tell you that your question is being down voted just because you did not format it properly.

Comment: Can u tell me how to add multiple spaces ,line breaks , and proper code formatting ?